# Creating the website that tracks the location of products

Tags: vs-web-site-project

I have a small company on my own that I deliver my products to my customers.

For each product, we have a specific tag to put in the system. And I want to create a website that uses those specific tags to track the location (kinda like Amazon, USPS). The location doesn't need to be specific, just the city and state. Does anyone have an idea how to do that?

I'm a complete beginner. I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Theres four disciplines involved in writing a website but you can skimp on all of them except for html. You will need to know html which is an extensive set of tags but you only need to know a few of them. To do what you propose, will take knowledge of all four disciplines.

1. HTML - the sites content will be written in HTML
2. CSS  - the style of the content such as whether the fonts are serif or sans
3. JS   - this causes the browser to do things beyond merely showing the page
4. PHP  - this causes the server to do things beyond merely sending the page

What you have given is a software requirement. These are taken by systems analysts and turned into a software specification by asking for more information from the person who has the requirement and creating an accurate and exact mathematical model of what the software is expected to do. Software requirements are wishy washy things that are subject to alteration midway through the software development process but the software specification at any point must be exacy and free from ambiguity albeit that it can be altered as other needs are discovered.

If your intent on writing your own website, I highly recommend going to w3schools which will not only guide you through all four disciplines but will serve as a great place of reference throught out your website writing.

Your software requirement is ambiguous and further questions would be needed to provide you with much of an answer to your question and not alot of people on stack exchange will be prepared to just write your program for you unless you have some cold hard kerching to offer.